# How to search Unicode whitespace char in Lua

Tags: unicode, lua, whitespace, lua-patterns

I would like to search [Unicode whitespace chars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) in file using Lua. For ASCII we can use `%s` but I did not find anything to search whitespace chars in Unicode file.

Comment: Lua 5.1 and earlier do not support unicode characters.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Isn't that seeing things a bit too negative? Storing/concatenatin/forwarding work fine, and everything else can be built, though is not builtin.

Answer (score 3):

Lua 5.2 and earlier have little support for Unicode.

(The upcomming) Lua 5.3 provides a basic UTF-8 library. However, it still doesn't know the meaning of the character (like *what is a whitespace character*). You need to do that part yourself after iterating each code point with [`utf8.codes`](http://www.lua.org/work/doc/manual.html#pdf-utf8.codes).

```
--table to be filled 
local whitespace = {0x9, 0xA, 0xB, 0xC, 0xD, 0x20, 0x85, 0xA0, 0x1680, 0x2000, 0x2001}

local str = 'hello\u{2000}world\n'
for _, c in utf8.codes(str) do
    for _, v in ipairs(whitespace) do
        if c == v then
            print 'whitespace found'
        end
    end
end
```